# Toggle item in an array react

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I want to toggle a property of an object in an array. The array looks as follows. This is being used in a react component and When a user clicks on a button I want to toggle the winner.

```
const initialFixtures = [{
    teams: {
      home: 'Liverpool',
      away: 'Manchester Utd'
    },
    winner: 'Liverpool'
  },
  {
    teams: {
      home: 'Chelsea',
      away: 'Fulham'
    },
    winner: 'Fulham'
  }, ,
  {
    teams: {
      home: 'Arsenal',
      away: 'Tottenham'
    },
    winner: 'Arsenal'
  }
];
```

My react code looks something like this

```
function Parent = () => {

  const [fixtures, setUpdateFixtures] = useState(initialFixtures)
  const toggleWinner = (index) => {
     const updatedFixtures = fixtures.map((fixture, i) => {
           if (i === index) {
                return {
                    ...fixture,
                    winner: fixture.winner === home ? away : home,
                };
            } else {
                return fixture;
            }
     }) 
     setUpdateFixtures(updatedFixtures);
  }

  return <Fixtures fixtures={fixtures} toggleWinner={toggleWinner} />;

}


function Fixtures = ({ fixtures, toggleWinner }) => { 
  fixtures.map((fixture, index) => ( 
    <div>
        <p>{fixture.winner} </p>
    <button onClick = {() => toggleWinner(index)}> Change Winner</button> 
    </div>
  ))
}
```

the code works but it feels like it is a bit too much. I am sure there is a better more succinct way of doing this. Can anyone advise? I do need to pass the fixtures in from the parent of the `Fixture` component for architectural reasons.

Comment: Where's `changeWinner` function?

Comment: Where and the `home` and `away` variables declared ?

Comment: _the code works but it feels like it is a bit too much._ Code review requests are off-topic here. Look at [CR](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Quick question. How is this: `function Parent = () => {` working??

Comment: it is a functional component being rendered in App. It is using Hooks if that is what you are asking?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
const updatedFixtures = [...fixtures];
const fixture = updatedFixtures[i];
updatedFixtures[i] = {
  ...fixture,
  winner: fixture.winner === fixture.teams.home ? fixture.teams.away : fixture.teams.home,
};
```

Comment: this will mutate the array though, no?

Comment: It will only mutate the updatedFixtures array. As this one is not part of  the state (yet) you can mutate it however you like.

Comment: If your concern were about the const declaration, [mdn states that](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const#Description) `The const declaration creates a read-only reference to a value. It does not mean the value it holds is immutable, just that the variable identifier cannot be reassigned. `

Answer (score 2):

You can [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) the fixtures array into three parts:

- from 0 to `index`: `fixtures.slice(0, index)`. This part is moved to the new array intact.
- The single item at `index`. This part/item is thrown away because of being changed and a new item is substituted.
- The rest of the array: `fixtures.slice(index + 1)`.

Next, put them into a new array:

```
const newFixtures = [
    ...fixtures.slice(0, index),    // part 1
    {/* new item at 'index' */},    // part 2
    ...fixtures.slice(index + 1)    // part 3
];
```

To construct the new item:

- Using [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax):

  ```
  const newFixture = {
      ...oldFixture,
      winner: /* new value */
  };
  ```
- Using [`Object.assign`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign):

  ```
  const newFixture = Object.assign({}, oldFixture, {
      winner: /* new value */
  });
  ```

Answer (score 1):

if you write your code in such a way - this will do the job.

```
const toggleWinner = index => {
    const { winner, teams: { home, away } } = fixtures[index];
    fixtures[index].winner = winner === home ? away : home;

    setUpdateFixtures([...fixtures]);
};
```

Setting a new array of fixtures to state is completely enough to trigger `render` on `Fixtures` component.

I have made a [working example](https://codesandbox.io/s/8l18v9q7l9) for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
      const toggleWinner = (index) => {
        let  updatedFixtures = [...fixtures].splice(index, 1, {...fixtures[index],
         winner: fixtures[index].winner === fixtures[index].teams.home
         ? fixtures[index].teams.away : fixtures[index].teams.home})

        setUpdateFixtures(updatedFixtures);
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use libraries like immer to update nested states easily.

```js
const initialFixtures = [{
    teams: {
      home: 'Liverpool',
      away: 'Manchester Utd'
    },
    winner: 'Liverpool'
  },
  {
    teams: {
      home: 'Chelsea',
      away: 'Fulham'
    },
    winner: 'Fulham'
  }, ,
  {
    teams: {
      home: 'Arsenal',
      away: 'Tottenham'
    },
    winner: 'Arsenal'
  }
];

const newState = immer.default(initialFixtures, draft => {
  draft[1].winner = "something";
});

console.log(newState);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/immer@1.0.1/dist/immer.umd.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are comfortable to use a class based approach, you can try something like this:

- Create a class that holds property value for team.
- Create a boolean property in this class, say `isHomeWinner`. This property will decide the winner.
- Then create a getter property `winner` which will lookup `this.isHomeWinner` and will give necessary value.
- This will enable you to have a clean `toggle` function: `this.isHomeWinner = !this.isHomeWinner`.

You can also write your `toggleWinner` as:

```js
const toggleWinner = (index) => {
  const newArr = initialFixtures.slice();
  newArr[index].toggle();
  return newArr;
};
```

This looks clean and declarative. Note, if immutability is necessary then only this is required. If you are comfortable with mutating values, just pass `fixture.toggle` to your react component. You may need to bind context, but that should work as well.

So it would look something like:

```js
function Fixtures = ({ fixtures, toggleWinner }) => { 
  fixtures.map((fixture, index) => ( 
    <div>
      <p>{fixture.winner} </p>
      <button onClick = {() => fixture.toggle() }> Change Winner</button> 

      // or
      // <button onClick = { fixture.toggle.bind(fixture) }> Change Winner</button> 
    </div>
  ))
}
```

---

Following is a sample of class and its use:

```js
class Fixtures {
  constructor(home, away, isHomeWinner) {
    this.team = {
      home,
      away
    };
    this.isHomeWinner = isHomeWinner === undefined ? true : isHomeWinner;
  }

  get winner() {
    return this.isHomeWinner ? this.team.home : this.team.away;
  }

  toggle() {
    this.isHomeWinner = !this.isHomeWinner
  }
}

let initialFixtures = [
  new Fixtures('Liverpool', 'Manchester Utd'),
  new Fixtures('Chelsea', 'Fulham', false),
  new Fixtures('Arsenal', 'Tottenham'),
];

const toggleWinner = (index) => {
  const newArr = initialFixtures.slice();
  newArr[index].toggle();
  return newArr;
};

initialFixtures.forEach((fixture) => console.log(fixture.winner))
console.log('----------------')
initialFixtures = toggleWinner(1);
initialFixtures.forEach((fixture) => console.log(fixture.winner))

initialFixtures = toggleWinner(2);
console.log('----------------')
initialFixtures.forEach((fixture) => console.log(fixture.winner))
```

Comment: thanks for taking the time to answer, but it doesn't really fit with what I want to do.